# How to stop MacBook Air from going into Power Save mode

Tags: macbook-air, macos-highsierra

My MacBook screen goes dark ~ 60 seconds.  Where can I find the settings to change that?  I've searched the web and answers indicate going into settings, but on High Sierra, this doesn't seem correct.

This is what I get when I click on system prefs:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System Preferences > Energy Saver.

It hasn’t changed in decades. It’s still there in High Sierra.

I suppose it could also be

System Preferences > Desktop & Screen Saver > Screen Saver  > Start after: [ XX Minutes ].

Updated: Your new screenshot shows that System Preferences is opening to show the iCloud pref pane only. You need to click the button that looks like a grid of dots to get back to the main view where you can select pref panes from a grid of icons.

Comment: I've tried that, but I don't get those option.  Please see the edit to my question.  I've added a screenshot of what I get when I click System Preferences.

Comment: @MartinMuldoon I’ve updated my Answer to help you get back to the main screen of System Preferences.

Comment: @MartinMuldoon Glad I could help. Honestly it’s weird that it got stuck on one pref pane quitting the app and re-launching it should have returned you to the main icon grid view as well. ‍♂️

Comment: What's even stranger based on what you just said, is that I have to Macbooks and both had the issue.  Cheers!